# change the background of this email template

Tags: html, css, html-email

I wanted to change the blue and grey background of this email template to an Image but can't seem to change it completely. Please help

[This is the link to Html Code](http://jsfiddle.net/WUTN5/)

I tried to edit the body tag but it doesn't change anything

```
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
```

Comment: You can check my answer. may be it will help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `background-color` from this css id/class :

`#preheaderBackground`, `#templatePreheader`, `#headerBackground`, `#templateHeader`

Comment: Thanks for your time but I wanted to change it to an image

Comment: Then you can give it as `background-image`

Comment: Its not changing when I added background-image="abc.jpg" in #templatePreheader itsbackground changed to grey color

Comment: make fiddle , so can look into it

Comment: remove `background-color` from `#preheaderBackground`

Comment: And set `background: url("http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/images-photo.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;` for `#templatePreheader`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WUTN5/3/)

```
#templatePreheader, #templateHeader, 
.preheaderContainer{background:Red !important}
#templateBody{background:#000 !important}
.mcnTextContentContainer{background:#f90 !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow that's a mess of html tables-within-tables.

The colors are set for various id's used by the tables. I found: templatePreheader, preheaderBackground & templateHeader for the blue, and templateBody for the grey. But that's gonna be bad to maintain - I assume you've inherited it from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
To change the blue color, search this class

#preheaderBackground{
            /*@change this*/background-color:#2d539c;
            /*@editable*/border-top:0;
            /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
        }
just change the background-color to whatever you want.

and to change gray color, search this class

#templateBody{
            /*@change this*/background-color:#F5F5F5;
            /*@editable*/border-top:0;
            /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
        }

just change the background-color to whatever you want.
```